# Disk configuration on Ubuntu server for rook-ceph in kubernetes cluster

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, kubernetes

I recently set up my Kubernetes cluster with three worker and one master node, as storage service I'm using rook-ceph. As I know the rook pods require a raw disk in order to run the osd-pods.

Last time I managed to create them as well within a disk partition (primary) that I labeled as 'physical volume'. The OSD-pods where running. back then. The problem now is that I cannot recreate this state again.

Does anyone know how to configure a disk partition (created with **fdisk**), such that it gets recognized as a raw disk on its own? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

If the problem lies within the image tags (for Ceph/ceph:14.XXX and rook/ceph 1.0.0), which image tags should I use?

The last time it worked for me I used the files from Rooks GitHub page: https://github.com/rook/rook/tree/master/cluster/examples/kubernetes/ceph

Comment: You should have added an answer instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I could recreate it and the solution is that you indeed have to clean up the disk. For this you can use **fdisk** (delete all partitions) and then unmount everything that is mounted to the certain disk. After that remove the unmounted directories from **/etc/fstab**. Then you are good to go!